# Threads syncronization with ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I'm trying to implement some logic when I create main(father) thread witch executes several other threads. Then it waits for some condition which child threads creates. After condition is meet the father executes some more child threads.
The problem that when I use wait/notify I have java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException exception. Here is the code:

```
public class MyExecutor {

final static ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10);
final static ExecutorService svc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
static final ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 8, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue);

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final MyExecutor me =  new MyExecutor();
    svc.execute(new Runnable()  {
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Main Thread");
                me.execute(threadPool, 1);
                System.out.println("Main Thread waiting");
                wait();
                System.out.println("Main Thread notified");
                me.execute(threadPool, 2);
                Thread.sleep(100);
                threadPool.shutdown();
                threadPool.awaitTermination(20000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    svc.shutdown();
    svc.awaitTermination(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("Main Thread finished");
}

public void execute(ThreadPoolExecutor tpe, final int id) {
    tpe.execute(new Runnable()  {
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Child Thread " + id);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("Child Thread " + id + " finished");
                notify();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

When I comment wait and notify line I have the following output: 
Main Thread
Main Thread waiting
Main Thread notified
Child Thread 1
Child Thread 2
Child Thread 1 finished
Child Thread 2 finished
Main Thread finished

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a series of design flaws in your code:

---

Calling both `wait()` and `notify()` must occur only when you are the owner of the lock of the object:

```
synchronized(foo) {
    foo.wait();
}
```

---

You are calling `wait()` and `notify()` on different objects (inner classes!) - if one threads is waiting on one object, you must call `notify` on the **same** object.

---

There is a possibility of missed `notify` when this:

```
me.execute(threadPool, 1);
```

is called before `wait` - **very** serious bug (race condition possibility).

Others might suggest you using some higher level synchronization methods, but it is crucial to understand the basics.

Comment: +1 I was trying to figure out a way to explain that to them, given that the code provided is so out of whack.

Comment: Thank you. It is working now with synchronized(svc) {
     svc.notify();
     }

Comment: @Brian Roach: unfortunately `wait/notify` construct is very fragile and verbose, lots of places to make a mistake. @justme1 Consider using some dedicated object (`final Object lock = new Object()`) for locking or lock on `MyExecutor` (when you get rid of all the statics). And please accept the answer for the benefit of both of us :-).

Comment: I'll try with this apporach as well. Thank you

Comment: The static was just for quick mock up I'm not going to use the code exactly as it. :)

Comment: dont forget wait() should be called from within a loop (ie, while (!condition) wait();)